# MPI_Scatterv segfault

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I'm just starting out with MPI programming and decided to make a simple distributed qsort using OpenMPI. To distribute parts of the array I want to sort I'm trying to use MPI_Scatterv, however the following code segfaults on me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 26
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int my_rank, nr_procs;

    int* data_in, *data_out;
    int* sizes;
    int* offsets;

    srand(time(0));

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nr_procs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    // everybody generates the control tables
    int nr_workers = nr_procs-1;
    sizes = malloc(sizeof(int)*nr_workers);
    offsets = malloc(sizeof(int)*nr_workers);

    int nr_elems = ARRAY_SIZE/nr_workers;

    // basic distribution
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
        sizes[i] = nr_elems;
    }
    // distribute the remainder
    int left = ARRAY_SIZE%nr_workers;
    int curr_worker = 0;
    while (left) {
        ++sizes[curr_worker];
        curr_worker = (++curr_worker)%nr_workers;
        --left;
    }   
    // offsets
    int curr_offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
        offsets[i] = curr_offset;
        curr_offset += sizes[i];
    }


    if (my_rank == 0) {
        // root
        data_in = malloc(sizeof(int)*ARRAY_SIZE);
        data_out = malloc(sizeof(int)*ARRAY_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
            data_in[i] = rand();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
            printf("%d at %d\n", sizes[i], offsets[i]);
        }

        MPI_Scatterv (data_in, sizes, offsets, MPI_INT, data_out, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    } else {
        // worker
        printf("%d has %d elements!\n",my_rank, sizes[my_rank-1]);
        // alloc the input buffer
        data_in = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizes[my_rank-1]);

        MPI_Scatterv(NULL, NULL, NULL, MPI_INT, data_in, sizes[my_rank-1], MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("%d got:\n", my_rank);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes[my_rank-1]; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", data_in[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

How would I go about using Scatterv? Am I doing something wrong with allocating my input buffer from inside the worker code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some part in your code to get something working.

`MPI_Scatter()` will send data to every processors, including himself. According to your program, processor 0 expects `ARRAY_SIZE` integers, but `sizes[0]` is much smaller.
There are other problems on other processus : MPI_Scatter will send `sizes[my_rank]` integers, but `sizes[my_rank-1]` will be expected...

Here is a code that scatters `data_in` from 0 to all processors, including 0. Therefore i added 1 to `nr_workers` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 26
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int my_rank, nr_procs;

    int* data_in, *data_out;
    int* sizes;
    int* offsets;

    srand(time(0));

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nr_procs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    // everybody generates the control tables
    int nr_workers = nr_procs;
    sizes = malloc(sizeof(int)*nr_workers);
    offsets = malloc(sizeof(int)*nr_workers);

    int nr_elems = ARRAY_SIZE/nr_workers;

    // basic distribution
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
        sizes[i] = nr_elems;
    }
    // distribute the remainder
    int left = ARRAY_SIZE%nr_workers;
    int curr_worker = 0;
    while (left) {
        ++sizes[curr_worker];
        curr_worker = (++curr_worker)%nr_workers;
        --left;
    }   
    // offsets
    int curr_offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
        offsets[i] = curr_offset;
        curr_offset += sizes[i];
    }

    if (my_rank == 0) {
        // root
        data_in = malloc(sizeof(int)*ARRAY_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
            data_in[i] = rand();
            printf("%d %d \n",i,data_in[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nr_workers; ++i) {
            printf("%d at %d\n", sizes[i], offsets[i]);
        }


    } else {
        printf("%d has %d elements!\n",my_rank, sizes[my_rank]);
    }
    data_out = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizes[my_rank]);

    MPI_Scatterv (data_in, sizes, offsets, MPI_INT, data_out, sizes[my_rank], MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("%d got:\n", my_rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes[my_rank]; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", data_out[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(data_out);
    if(my_rank==0){
        free(data_in);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding memory managment, `data_in` and `data_out` should be freed at the end of the code.

Is it what you wanted to do ? Good luck with qsort ! I think you are not the first one to sort integers using MPI. See [parallel sort using mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278490/parallel-sort-using-mpi/20302705#20302705). Your way to generate random numbers on the 0 processus and then scatter them is the right way to go. I think you will be interrested by his `TD_Trier()` function for communication. Even if you change `tri_fusion(T, 0, size - 1);` for `qsort(...)`...

Bye,

Francis

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and useful tips! As a beginner I find documentation regarding MPI pretty lacking - sure there are a lot of references, but most of the material is pretty poorly explained. It didn't even occur to me, that the root process sends data to itself too (which in hindsight makes perfect sense). Sadly I cannot +rep you for your contribution, because I'm too new :(

Comment: I'm not Deino, but I do like his reference pages about MPI. You might try giving it a look. http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Scatter.html